# Pagination in csv export using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have some admin panel in application built it with ActiveAdmin gem. I also have csv export there. The problem is that by default ActiveAdmin exports records to csv using batch which size is 1000. I want to change it to some smaller number. I tried to add in my ActiveAdmin resource something like that:

```
  before_filter do
    @per_page = 10
  end
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `batch_size` is a hard coded value in the `ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder` class ([view on github](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/c6510db25864c869256f5ba34120c5f7c8ada825/lib/active_admin/csv_builder.rb#L126)). That being the case, it seems that ActiveAdmin has not left any way to configure this except by monkey patching this method in an initializer:

```
ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder.class_eval do
  private
  def batch_size
    10
  end
end
```

You might want to make a feature request to ActiveAdmin on Github instead because this isn't an ideal solution.

Another thing you could try is (but it is pretty hacky):

```
ActiveAdmin::CSVBuilder.class_eval do
  attr_writter :batch_size

  private
  def batch_size
    @batch_size ||= 1000
  end
end
```

That way you can pass in the batch_size option in the [ActiveAdmin dsl method for csv](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/b44b4f4896ef78b50c35c82a343356d68b937cde/lib/active_admin/resource_dsl.rb#L76):

```
csv do
  batch_size = 10
  #...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But your last example with configurable batch_size is not working. When I try to download csv it returns:

2015-11-29 15:40:08 +0100: Read error: #<ArgumentError: Unknown options:  batch_size.>

Comment: I updated my answer as well for a way to do it without passing options. It seems that options that you set up here are also sent to CSV to generate each row. That could be the origin of the error you got (seeing the full trace would help). The updated code is pretty hacky though, and would only work because the `csv` block is called before the `paginated_collection` is called: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/b44b4f4896ef78b50c35c82a343356d68b937cde/lib/active_admin/csv_builder.rb#L45

Comment: Your solution works perfectly but it should be instance variable here:
@batch_size = 10

Comment: Cool so you got it to work? Yeah ot could be an instance varriable, but since I setup an attr_writter for batch_size, I thought it would work as a method call.

Comment: Typo Fix =>  `attr_writer `